# Direct ethernet vs router+ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, internet-speed

I have a 60m long CAT5 Ethernet cable connected to my cable modem. When I connect my laptop directly to the ethernet cable speed tests show my maximum internet speed (20Mbps). If I connect the 60m ethernet cable to a router, then speed tests go down to at least 50% (10Mbps) even if the laptop has a wired connection to the router. I have tried multiple router with no luck.

Does anybody have any idea what could the issue be? Could it be a wiring issue?

Answer (score 1):

10MBit can mean that autonegotiation failed, either between your laptop and the router, or between the router and the modem. Without being able to analyze the situation on site, I'd point my finger to one of the cables.

Or the routers you are using are just too old and don't support any higher speeds than 10MBit (on the WAN port).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. So I should probably just cut the end of the cables and reterminate them?

Comment: Before doing that, just try it with a professionally assembled cable first. If you don't have access to any, then yes, reterminate.

Comment: quick test, for many but not all network cards - if the light's green, you've got 1000Base-T, if it's yellow you've only got 100Base-T.

Comment: I reterminated the cable and it works fine. Apparently the guy who first terminated it just randomly chose the wires. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Glad to hear it. It was the only thing that made sense.